# How to change FileSystem from, msdos to ext3/ext4 on a specific drive

Tags: 14.04, filesystem, ssd, ext4, ms-dos

I am relatively new to Ubuntu and I have recently added a new 480Gb+ SSD drive. When I attempted to install a program onto the drive it wouldn't allow it to happen and a error would occur. I ended up looking at the properties of the drive and realised that its file system was "msdos" and I am assuming that is the issue. I looked all over online and couldn't find anything to convert it to a Ext3/Ext/4 on a specific drive. HELP

Comment: to convert to ext4 you need to format the drive, you should backup all the data on that drive since all of it will be deleted

Comment: Use `gparted` to format the drive `sudo apt-get install gparted`

Comment: If you already had a bunch of data on there that you didn't want to move somewhere else, you could use the PartEd Magic to easily do the conversion for you.  What it does behind the scenes is shrink the original partition, create a new one, copy files, delete the old one, and grow the new one.   Then again, if you don't have space to copy (i.e. back up) files from a partition, you probably should risk an operation like that; thus the recommendation to back up the data and reformat the partition yourself is still valid and will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
 fmsdos /dev/sda ext3
```

and it might work fine this way.